# Is there any limit on the value returned by `count()` in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any bound on the value returned by the PySpark API `.count()`?

For ex, let `C` be any very large RDD. Following is the pyspark code snippet:

```
t = C.count()
```

Under what circumstances will the value of `t` be invalid or undefined?

Answer (score 0):

From the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1158) itself :

`def count(): Long = sc.runJob(this, Utils.getIteratorSize _).sum`

as you can see, count returns `Long` so maximum size for t will be limited by the definition of `Long` which is `64 bit signed value = -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 i.e. (-2^63 to 2^63-1, inclusive)` or in other words count can go up to 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616.